# How to setup sdl 2.0 on commandline?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am following the tutorial at:[lazyfoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php)
Have unzipped the SDL2.0x path:
    `C:\mingw_dev_lib`
and copied items in "i686-w64-mingw32" to the folder above!
Set Environment Variable path to:
    `C:\mingw_dev_lib\bin`

Now running the code:

```
g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp

01_hello_SDL.cpp:5: SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use longer command than that. It is already [explained](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php#3) in that page. Please read all of the page!

Comment: I used that before posting it here, :/ didn't help

Comment: What error are you getting using `g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL` command?